# javascript slideshow does not change image

Tags: javascript

I'm making a header for my site, and I want to have it like a slideshow.
The problem is that the images won't change. It shows only 1 images, and the rest won't show up.
Code:

```js
//Array with the paths to the images
var image = new Array("img/header/header1.png", "img/header/header2.png", "img/header/header3.png");

//imageNumber to change the image, and imageLenght for the array lenght - 1 
var imageNumber = 0;
var imageLength = image.length -1;

//Call changeImage()
changeImage();

//Function to change the image
function changeImage() {

 //use strict because I use dreamweaver and it needs that(I don't know why)
 "use strict";
 //Add 1 to imageNumber for choosing a image(in "document.slideshow.src = image[imageNumber];") 
 imageNumber++;

 //Check if image number is not below 0 or above the array index
 if(imageNumber < 0) {

  imageNumber = imageLength;

 } else if(imageNumber > imageLength) {

  imageNumber = 0;

 }

 //Change the image
 document.header.src = image[imageNumber];
 
 //recalling every second
 setTimeout(changeImage, 1000);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Tommie's HOME</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/header_slideshow.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="big_wrapper">
<nav>
<ul id="n1">
<li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" width="100px"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="n2">
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div id="content">
<header>
<img src="img/header/header1.png" name="header" />
</header>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you know the problem, feel free to reply.

Kind regards,

Tom

Comment: Although there are much better ways to achieve the slide show effect, your code seems to work as intended. Did you check whether you correctly specified the path to your script and/or images? Could it be the case that your images look all the same? ...?

Comment: I checked all of it, and it still doesn't work. I'm gonna ask it tommorow at my school.